# Working WCF with NLB server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking, load-balancing

Im starting the architecture of a new project using WCF, but im not the right person to make some network considerations, so im doing some research but cannot find the answers to these questions:

1) We´ll host the `WCF` service in a common `Windows Service` app in 2 servers and we´ll have another server to make the `Load-Balancing` job using the `WNLB`. The fact that we are hosting the `WCF` in a `Windows Service` app can disturb the `NLB` job?

2) Before my research i thought the load balancing was tought to configure, but with NLB it seems to be very simple, its really that simple?

Things to consider:
1) The binding will be `basicHttpBinding`

Thanks!

Comment: this belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: We have 2 load balanced servers at work where both servers run a Windows Service that hosts a WCF service.  We haven't experienced any problems with the load balancing.  But I agree - this is probably better suited to serverfault.com.